# Cannot call a member function pointer on a object typecasted as void *

Tags: c++, pointers, function-pointers

So the very reason I want to use member function pointer is to invoke function from a place where the type of the object is not known and where all objects are treated as void * objects. But I am unable to do so even though rationally it seems function pointers point to the address of a subroutine and hence type of the object should be immaterial. My assumption is that all that the system has to do is set the "this" pointer to the object on which the member function pointer was called. Below is my code. How can I achieve what I want

```
class C2
{
    public:
       int y;
       void SetValue(int);
};

void C2::SetValue(int k)
{
    cout<<"Setting Value inside C2"<<endl;
    y=k;
}

int main()
{
    void (C2::*f)(int);
    C2 *Ob=new C2();
    void *Ob2=(void *)Ob;
    f = &C2::SetValue;
    ((Ob2)->*f)(10);
}
```

This code is not even compiling with VC++ compiler with the error as

> error C2296: '->*' : illegal, left operand has type 'void *'

Comment: How can you have a member function pointer without knowing the type the member belongs to? In your example, `f` is of type `void (C2::*)(int)`, so you know that it must be called on an instance of `C2`.

Comment: You want an implicit conversion from `void` to your type?!

Comment: But I have already set the function pointer to point to the member function of a particular class which is the class C2. So expectation is that irrespective of the object on which the function pointer is called, the function should just get executed

Comment: Sounds like you might want to use inheritance and virtual functions. `void *` should not be something you consider offten in modern C++.

Comment: @Raks "Irrespective of the object on which the function pointer is called, the function should just get executed" => This goes against the C++ type system. C++ is strongly typed and statically typed: if you have a function that expects an int as a parameter, you can only call it with an int. The same goes for member function pointer, the compiler prevents you from calling the member function with a `void *` because this is not typesafe (your object could be something else than a `C2`), so you must explicitely "bypass" the type system by using a cast: `(static_cast<C2>(Ob2)->*f)(10);`

Comment: C++ being strongly typed is indeed the problem, I want to skip the type system completely hence nowhere in the code I want to have the name of the type. From whatever answers I've got, it seems there is is'nt a way

Answer (score 1):

Well the simple fix to your problem is to `static_cast` your `Ob2` to the right type, since you need to know the class which the function belongs to anyway:

```
(static_cast<C2*>(Ob2)->*f)(10);
```

You could automate this with templates:

```
template <typename Ret, class C, typename... Params, typename... Args>
Ret callMemPtr (Ret (C::*fun) (Params...), void* obj, Args&&... args)
{
    return (static_cast<C*>(obj)->*fun)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);   
}

//usage
callMemPtr(f,Ob2,10);
```

However, this seems like an odd approach to take. You might be better off using inheritance or some form of type erasure.

Answer (score 1):

> rationally it seems function pointers point to the address of a subroutine and hence type of the object should be immaterial.

Although that would certainly be true for pointers to free-standing functions, as well as pointers to `static` member functions, pointers to instance member functions are different. A pointer to a member function might be a data structure, rather than a single pointer, because it needs to support virtual dispatch.

Consider this code fragment:

```
#include <iostream>
struct Base {
    virtual void foo() = 0;
};
struct Derived : public Base {
    virtual void foo() {
        std::cout << "Hello" << std::endl;
    }
};
typedef void (Base::*MemFn)();
int main() {
    Derived d;
    MemFn f(&Base::foo);
    (d.*f)();
    return 0;
}
```

Above, `f` is a pointer to `Base::foo`, yet `Derived::foo` gets invoked ([demo](http://ideone.com/K2UtLh)).

That is one reason why you cannot convert function pointers to `void*`. Void pointers are pointers to data, while function pointers are pointers to code.

Comment: So then what does the variable "f" actually point to when we say f=&C::SetValue with f declared as      void (C2::*f)(int);

Comment: @Raks The actual structure of member function pointer is specific to the compiler. The compiler decides what it needs to store there in order to be able to figure out what to call. For example, if virtual dispatch is implemented using vtables, this structure could include an offset into vtable where the actual pointer is stored.

Comment: But if the funtion pointer is not a virtual function then the virtual table lookup should'nt even be required. I thought all that should matter is setting the "this" pointer to the object on which the function is called.

Comment: @Raks Here `MemFn f(&Base::foo);` the compiler knows that the function is `virtual`. However, here `(d.*f)();` it has no idea if `f` is `virtual` or not, and it must be prepared to handle both possibilities.

Comment: In my example the compiler does know that "f" points to a non virtual function because that is how its been declared hence upfront the compiler knows that there won't be any vtable lookup required. Well all of this is just a logical assumption.

Comment: @Raks `f` has been declared as a pointer to a void, no argument, member function of `C2`. That is all the compiler knows when you invoke the `->*f` operator. Certainly, your class has no virtual member functions with matching signature now, but the compiler cannot start using this knowledge to make your code compilable, only to break it when when you add `virtual void SetOtherValue(int);` to your class, with no other changes.

Comment: void (C2::*f)(int); f = &C2::SetValue; Here f is made to point to a specific member function SetValue. Why should compiler even bother about this function being resolving to something else.

Comment: @Raks Because the places where a pointer is set and places where the pointer is used could be in different translation units. The pointer must be self-sufficient from the moment when it is set. At the point of invocation the compiler has no idea what specific function is set in the pointer (otherwise, the pointer would be useless). It needs to have complete information to make an invocation, though.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you want this but you can go yolo and do it like this:

```
#include <iostream>

class test
{
public:
    test(){}
    void echo(int x)
    {
        std::cout << "I'm being called: " << x << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    test t;
    (t.*((void(test::*)(int))&test::echo))(10);

    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```